# Why does the voltage in half-bride capacitors become unbalanced when increasing the switching frequency?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I built a basic low power HB converter (for simplicity I am only showing a representation of the power stage).

[image: HB converter]

I did notice that the DC center point gets unbalanced when I increase the switching frequency. For instance, I measure no major difference in the voltage across C1 and C2 at 75kHz (DC point = Vin/2 prox.) but the difference is more than 3V when switching at 150kHz (increasing proportionally with frequency) being the low side capacitor voltage lower than the high side.

I have tried different things to compensate the unbalance (pre-screening on C1 and C2 to make sure their values are not different, equalizer resistors across C1 and C2, DC blocking capacitor in series with the transformer, even intentionally changing the value of the low side capacitor to change the capacitive voltage divider ratio) but no difference in the result.

Since the PCB layout is not very symmetrical due to mechanical constraints, I take my chances on PCB issues (which may introduce large parasitic effects on the pulse driving paths introducing delays that could cause the unbalance... not confirmed) but I find this unbalance against switching frequency too noticeable in such a short frequency increase considering 150kHz is not a crazy value for a switching power supply.

Have you ever seen something like this on a HB converter?

I Edit to add more details and answer the question from brhans:

@brhans: "Are you absolutely certain that your half-bridge FETs are being driven symmetrically? There's no tiny difference in dead-time and both high & low side rise & fall times are the same?"

Not sure. I'm using an UC3825 pwm controller and, as the the difference between capacitor's voltages increases, the pulses go less symmetrical. I guess the controller tries to compensate the difference adjusting the low/high side pulse widths.

About the dead-time there might be a small difference but I already have plenty of dead time at nominal operation (duty is around 20% so there is roughly 15% of deadtime between pulses). The rise/fall times are a different story, I am using the IR21113 driver and the same resistor (31.6Ohm) between the MOSFETs gates and the driver's output (see the sch below) but the PCB path from the driver to the transistors are very different. I think this may change the rising/falling times specially if the layout introduces big parasitic capacitance/inductance....

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this is answerable until you give the part numbers for the capacitors (are they the same, or perhaps they have different performance?) and images of the PCB layout.

Comment: Is it transitioning from DCM at 75kHz to CCM at 150kHz? If there is dead-time at 75kHz it will naturally nullify any imbalance / flux-walking tendency.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that your half-bridge FETs are being driven symmetrically? There's no tiny difference in dead-time and both high & low side rise & fall times are the same?

Comment: @Null: Capacitors are the same, the part number is CH431C825KA30A7 (stacked ceramic capacitors 8.2uF, X7R 10%, 100V). I don't have the layout on hand, sorry about that.

Comment: @Adam Lawrence: No, in both cases it is working in CCM.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is not symmetrical at any rate.

T101 gate is driven from a charge pump and when switched, it behaves as "common drain"

T102 gate is powered from the VCC (somewhat different voltage) and when switched behaves as "common source" with its much worse frequency response because of the drain-source parasitics.

No matter how you try, some asymmetry in a circuit like this will always be present and it will depend on frequency because it mainly relates to the switching process.

Usually, it is not much of a problem, except as an indication that you are pushing your transistors to their switching time limits.